# Installer for .NET Framework WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, clickonce, msix

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 WPF application. (Maybe .NET 5 in the future) This is a business application to manage persons.

The application must connect to a web service to authenticate with a user and manage data.

The web service is deployed on the customer server.

Each customer has its own installation with its own server and database.

Before, it was a Silverlight application, so an installer was not necessary.

What I need :

- Create an installer that will install the WPF client application
- Deploy the installer when hosting the web service on the customer server (Ex. "intranet.mycustomer/myApp/ClientAppSetup.exe" )
- If possible, keep the URL of the server during installation, so that the application can call the web service, without having to ask the user to enter the URL again.
- The application must update automatically
- Installation should be as simple as possible
- If possible, do not be limited to windows 10
- Bonus : Since not all clients may have the latest version of the application, it would be usefull to be able to install the application several times on the same machine, with different versions and connecting to different servers (to do remote support or connect to different test systems)

What technology should I use to best manage my needs?

- ClickOnce
- MSIX (compatible with .NET Framework ?)
- Squirrel ?
- Other ?

I find the information difficult to find and there is little official and up-to-date documentation.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with it, but VSIX installer might help address your needs:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with ClickOnce before and it is a very easy tool. You have an option to generate a page where users can easily install the application. every time users open the application, Clickones compares the server version and the client version, and if it is necessary ClickOnes will update the client application (you can customize this part if you want it), the application will be installed as a normal program on the user's computer.

take a look at this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/

Comment: Thank you. Is it still used in 2020 ? Should I use their new MSIX instead ?